# Derivative of $\ln\left(\det \left(\mathbb{X}^T \mathbb{A} \mathbb{X} \mathbb{B}\right)\right)$ w.r.t. $\mathbb{X}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis

I would like to compute the following matrix derivative

$$\frac \partial {\partial\mathbb{X}} \ln\left(\det \left(\mathbb{X}^T \mathbb{A} \mathbb{X} \mathbb{B}\right)\right)=\text{?}$$

where

- $\mathbb{X}$  is a $(p\times d)$ semi-orthogonal matrix
- $\mathbb{A}$ is a $(p\times p)$ symmetric matrix
- $\mathbb{B}$ is a $(d\times d)$ symmetric matrix

I have checked a number of resources such as *The Matrix Cookbook*, but I cannot find any property such as this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: $$\ln\left(\det \left(\mathbb{X}^T \mathbb{A} \mathbb{X} \mathbb{B}\right)\right) = \ln\left(\det \left(\mathbb{X}^T \mathbb{A} \mathbb{X} \right) \det (\mathbb{B})\right) =  \ln\left(\det \left(\mathbb{X}^T \mathbb{A} \mathbb{X} \right) \right) + \ln \left( \det (\mathbb{B})\right)$$ Hence, one can assume that $\mathbb{B}$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Take a look at equation 54 in the [cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf). Then try to use the chain rule.

Comment: The question seems tolerably clear to me, according to matrix calculus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus. Can those who voted to close explain if I'm missing something?

Comment: Just commenting to share an useful resource to the OP: this derivative and another matrix derivatives can be computed on http://www.matrixcalculus.org/

Comment: I did not vote to close, but would definitely do so. No offense, but really, how many times will a derivative of log-det pop up as a "research" question on MO!

Comment: I simply wanted to compute the given derivative as I could not find such a result. Many thanks for the matrix calculus website.

Comment: @Suvrit Perhaps so, but the reason for closure should then be something other than "unclear what you're asking". It sends the wrong message.

Comment: This question was also posted on MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2155052/339790

Comment: And has an answer at Math.SE, which I assume is correct, in which case this question should remain closed, even if for the wrong reason. To the OP: please do not cross-post, or at least not without linking, at each SE site, to every other SE site where the problem is posted.